# How to check Purge Interval Replication Control of a database- lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Is there any way to check ***programatically*** that Purge Interval Replication Control for a database is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built a tool that parses the results from the console command

```
show directory xxxx
```

which look like this:

```
DbName                                Version Log  DAOS NIFNSF PIRC  ---Modified Time----
K:\DataHS\xxx\xx\xxxx\xxxx_online_test.nsf V9     N/A   No   No   Off  06/29/2016 01:46:28 PM
K:\DataHS\xxx\xx\xx_Config.nsf V9     N/A   No   No   Off  09/14/2017 07:35:05 AM
K:\DataHS\xxx\xx\TestFixer.nsf  V9     N/A   No   No   Off  08/14/2015 02:57:23 PM
K:\DataHS\xxx\xx\xxxxxWeb.nsf   V9     N/A   No   No   Off  09/14/2017 07:01:49 AM
K:\DataHS\xxx\xx\xxxx\xxxxx_Live.nsf V9     N/A   No   No   Off  03/10/2017 02:01:37 AM
```

I then remove the multiple spaces and find the third to last word. which is "Off" or "On"